# Nested ng-repeat with groupBy on Page Load or refresh in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I got some help coming this far. I just need to go one step further to achieve what I'm about. I'd like to group data by an attribute which currently gets passed by an ng-click action. I wish to have this done on page load or refresh. How can i achieve this from the code below? DO advice if there's a better way to achieve what i'm about. Thanks.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>
        Grouping Nested ngRepeat Lists In AngularJS
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>
        Grouping Nested ngRepeat Lists In AngularJS
    </h1>

    <p>
        Group by:
        <a ng-click="groupBy( 'brandName' )">Brand Name</a> -
        <a ng-click="groupBy( 'hair' )">Hair</a>
    </p>

    <!-- BEGIN: Outer ngRepeat. -->
    <div class="col s12" ng-repeat="group in groups" >
                                <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
      <a href="#">
                                <img ng-src="{{group.brandLogo}}" alt="" class="circle responsive-img activator card-profile-image2" onerror="this.src='../../assets/images/backgrounds/cj_avatar.jpg'">
                            </a>

      <p>Brand Name: {{ group.label }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body" ng-repeat="camp in group.camps">
      <ul class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4 m2 center-align">
        {{camp.campID}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m3 center-align">
            <b>{{camp.campName}}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m2 center-align">
            {{camp.campBudget}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m1 center-align">
            {{camp.campHits}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m2 center-align">
            {{camp.campDuration}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m2 right-align">
            <i class="material-icons ">insert_chart</i>
            <i class="material-icons">content_copy</i>
            <i class="material-icons ">delete_forever</i>
            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
                                </div>
    <!-- END: Outer ngRepeat. -->



    <!-- Load jQuery and AngularJS from the CDN. -->
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Load the app module and its classes. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Define our AngularJS application module.
        var demo = angular.module( "Demo", [] );
        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // I am the main controller for the application.
        demo.controller(
            "DemoController",
            function( $scope, $timeout ) {
                // -- Define Controller Methods. ------------ //
                // I sort the given collection on the given property.
                function sortOn( collection, brandName ) {
                    collection.sort(
                        function( a, b ) {
                            if ( a[ brandName ] <= b[ brandName ] ) {
                                return( -1 );
                            }
                            return( 1 );
                        }
                    );
                }
                // -- Define Scope Methods. ----------------- //
                // I group the friends list on the given property.
                $scope.groupBy = function( attribute ) {
                    // First, reset the groups.
                    $scope.groups = [];
                    // Now, sort the collection of friend on the
                    // grouping-property. This just makes it easier
                    // to split the collection.
                    sortOn( $scope.camps, attribute );
                    // I determine which group we are currently in.
                    var groupValue = "_INVALID_GROUP_VALUE_";
                    // As we loop over each friend, add it to the
                    // current group - we'll create a NEW group every
                    // time we come across a new attribute value.
                    for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.camps.length ; i++ ) {
                        var camp = $scope.camps[ i ];
                        // Should we create a new group?
                        if ( camp[ attribute ] !== groupValue ) {
                            var group = {
                                label: camp[ attribute ],
                                camps: []
                            };
                            groupValue = group.label;
                            $scope.groups.push( group );
                        }
                        // Add the friend to the currently active
                        // grouping.
                        group.camps.push( camp );
                    }
                };
                // -- Define Scope Variables. --------------- //
                // I am the raw collection of friends.
                $scope.camps = [
                    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/vodafone.jpg", brandName:"Vodafone", campID:032145, campName:"Y3 Twi Kor", campBudget:500, campHits:"7k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
                    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/vodafone.jpg", brandName:"Vodafone", campID:639885, campName:"X Bundle", campBudget:900, campHits:"6.2k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/vodafone.jpg", brandName:"Vodafone", campID:857745, campName:"One Ghana", campBudget:1000, campHits:"9k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/mtn.jpg", brandName:"MTN", campID:795554, campName:"Free Bonto", campBudget:1500, campHits:"8.1k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/mtn.jpg", brandName:"MTN", campID:722957, campName:"Anajo Y3 D3", campBudget:650, campHits:"1.2k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/mtn.jpg", brandName:"MTN", campID:769855, campName:"Y3n Ko Nkoa", campBudget:780, campHits:"6.4k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:742896, campName:"Drink for life", campBudget:7000, campHits:"3.8k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:087759, campName:"Pure as Spirit", campBudget:910, campHits:"1.7k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:085997, campName:" Nourish your thirst", campBudget:1200, campHits:"9.2k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:398745, campName:"Fountain of life", campBudget:9800, campHits:"8.5k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:297556, campName:" Spring of Youth", campBudget:250, campHits:"4k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""}

                ];
                // I am the grouped collection. Each one of these
                // will contain a sub-collection of friends.
                $scope.groups = [];
            }
        );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>
        Grouping Nested ngRepeat Lists In AngularJS
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>
        Grouping Nested ngRepeat Lists In AngularJS
    </h1>

    <p>
        Group by:
        <a ng-click="groupBy( 'brandName' )">Brand Name</a> -
        <a ng-click="groupBy( 'hair' )">Hair</a>
    </p>

    <!-- BEGIN: Outer ngRepeat. -->
    <div class="col s12" ng-repeat="group in groups" >
                                <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
      <a href="#">
                                <img ng-src="{{group.brandLogo}}" alt="" class="circle responsive-img activator card-profile-image2" onerror="this.src='../../assets/images/backgrounds/cj_avatar.jpg'">
                            </a>

      <p>Brand Name: {{ group.label }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body" ng-repeat="camp in group.camps">
      <ul class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s4 m2 center-align">
        {{camp.campID}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m3 center-align">
            <b>{{camp.campName}}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m2 center-align">
            {{camp.campBudget}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m1 center-align">
            {{camp.campHits}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m2 center-align">
            {{camp.campDuration}}
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 m2 right-align">
            <i class="material-icons ">insert_chart</i>
            <i class="material-icons">content_copy</i>
            <i class="material-icons ">delete_forever</i>
            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
                                </div>
    <!-- END: Outer ngRepeat. -->



    <!-- Load jQuery and AngularJS from the CDN. -->
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Load the app module and its classes. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Define our AngularJS application module.
        var demo = angular.module( "Demo", [] );
        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // -------------------------------------------------- //
        // I am the main controller for the application.
        demo.controller(
            "DemoController",
            function( $scope, $timeout ) {
                // -- Define Controller Methods. ------------ //
                // I sort the given collection on the given property.
                function sortOn( collection, brandName ) {
                    collection.sort(
                        function( a, b ) {
                            if ( a[ brandName ] <= b[ brandName ] ) {
                                return( -1 );
                            }
                            return( 1 );
                        }
                    );
                }
                // -- Define Scope Methods. ----------------- //
                // I group the friends list on the given property.
               
                $scope.groupBy = function( attribute ) {
                    // First, reset the groups.
                    $scope.groups = [];
                    // Now, sort the collection of friend on the
                    // grouping-property. This just makes it easier
                    // to split the collection.
                    sortOn( $scope.camps, attribute );
                    // I determine which group we are currently in.
                    var groupValue = "_INVALID_GROUP_VALUE_";
                    // As we loop over each friend, add it to the
                    // current group - we'll create a NEW group ever

                    // time we come across a new attribute value.
                    for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.camps.length ; i++ ) {
                        var camp = $scope.camps[ i ];
                        // Should we create a new group?
                        if ( camp[ attribute ] !== groupValue ) {
                            var group = {
                                label: camp[ attribute ],
                                camps: []
                            };
                            groupValue = group.label;
                            $scope.groups.push( group );
                        }
                        // Add the friend to the currently active
                        // grouping.
                        group.camps.push( camp );
                    }
                };
              
                // -- Define Scope Variables. --------------- //
                // I am the raw collection of friends.
                $scope.camps = [
                    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/vodafone.jpg", brandName:"Vodafone", campID:032145, campName:"Y3 Twi Kor", campBudget:500, campHits:"7k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
                    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/vodafone.jpg", brandName:"Vodafone", campID:639885, campName:"X Bundle", campBudget:900, campHits:"6.2k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/vodafone.jpg", brandName:"Vodafone", campID:857745, campName:"One Ghana", campBudget:1000, campHits:"9k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/mtn.jpg", brandName:"MTN", campID:795554, campName:"Free Bonto", campBudget:1500, campHits:"8.1k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/mtn.jpg", brandName:"MTN", campID:722957, campName:"Anajo Y3 D3", campBudget:650, campHits:"1.2k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/mtn.jpg", brandName:"MTN", campID:769855, campName:"Y3n Ko Nkoa", campBudget:780, campHits:"6.4k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:742896, campName:"Drink for life", campBudget:7000, campHits:"3.8k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:087759, campName:"Pure as Spirit", campBudget:910, campHits:"1.7k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:085997, campName:" Nourish your thirst", campBudget:1200, campHits:"9.2k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:398745, campName:"Fountain of life", campBudget:9800, campHits:"8.5k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""},
    {brandLogo:"../../assets/images/brands/voltic.jpg", brandName:"Voltic", campID:297556, campName:" Spring of Youth", campBudget:250, campHits:"4k", campDuration:"15 Days", campDesc:""}

                ];
                // I am the grouped collection. Each one of these
                // will contain a sub-collection of friends.
                $scope.groups = [];
               $scope.groupBy('brandName');
            }
        );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's quite simple actually. You just need to invoke your

```
$scope.groupBy('brandName')
```

Somewhere in your controller.

Another cleaner approach would be(if you're planning to scale), use the `resolve` method in `ngRouter` or `uiRouter` resolve your data and preformat it before loading the page.

Comment: Thanks NikJohn. That was really simple. about the resolve method bit how do i apply it?

Comment: Again, it's quite simple. You need to first set up a route using `ngRouter` or `uiRouter`. You can follow [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) tutorial. Once done, you can define a `resolve` method in the state/route definition like [so](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter function to filter the results lets say that you are trying to form a table from the filtered result you can do it like this

```
    //example to group by propertyname 
    <table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in camps  | groupBy:'brandName' }">
    <td>{{x.campName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.campBudget}}</td>  
    </tr>

    //example to filter by a propertyValue
    <table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in camps  | filter:{ brandName: 'yourbrandname' }">
    <td>{{x.campName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.campBudget}}</td>  
    </tr>
    </table>
```

here i have used hardcoded values but you can use data binding in angular to dynamically change the brandname.

Comment: You were thinking along my line:  http://plnkr.co/edit/YSpSkASc65D8z3NNnP2D?p=preview